# Navigating back to Parent screens on pressing a Persistent Bottom NavBar Item

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-bottomnavigation

I am using [this](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2) library to display the bottom navbar when navigating to `sub screens` inside the `parent screen`. To gain a better view on this, one of the parent screens look like this,

[image]

I am currently navigating back to the `parent screens` using the back buttons I have added to `sub screens` .Because I couldn't find a way to navigate back to parent screen on clicking the `navbar item`.

I looked into a few similar questions on stackoverflow but I couldn't find an intuitive answer so far.

Following is how I have implemented my persistent bottom navbar with routes to each `sub page` from the `parent page`:

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  late PersistentTabController _controller;
  late BuildContext testContext;

  final screens = [
        () => HomeScreen(),
        () => TripsScreen(),
        () => HelpCenterScreen(),
        () => ProfileScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<PersistentBottomNavBarItem> _navBarsItems() => [
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: const ImageIcon(
              AssetImage("assets/bottom_navbar/home.png"),
            ),
            title: "Home",
            activeColorPrimary: Color(0xff2CC826),
            inactiveColorPrimary: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
            routeAndNavigatorSettings: RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
              initialRoute: "/",
              routes: {
                "/Settings": (final context) => const SettingsScreen(),
                "/store": (BuildContext context) =>
                    const StoreScreen(),
                "/Highlights": (BuildContext context) =>
                    const HighlightsScreen(),
                "/Cameras": (BuildContext context) => const CamerasScreen(),
                "/NewService": (BuildContext context) =>
                    const NewServiceScreen(),
                "/Notifications": (BuildContext context) =>
                const NotificationsScreen(),
                "/Languages" : (BuildContext context) => const LanguageSelection()
              },
            ),
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: const ImageIcon(
              AssetImage("assets/bottom_navbar/trips.png"),
            ),
            title: "Trips",
            activeColorPrimary: Color(0xff2CC826),
            inactiveColorPrimary: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
            routeAndNavigatorSettings: RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
              initialRoute: "/",
              routes: {
                "/From": (final context) => const FromSearchScreen(),
                "/To": (final context) => const ToSearchScreen(),
                "/Waypoint" : (final context) => const WaypointSearchScreen(),
              },
            ),
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: const ImageIcon(
              AssetImage("assets/bottom_navbar/help.png"),
            ),
            title: "Help",
            activeColorPrimary: Color(0xff2CC826),
            inactiveColorPrimary: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
            routeAndNavigatorSettings: RouteAndNavigatorSettings(
              initialRoute: "/",
              routes: {
                "/unit_manual": (final context) => const UnitManualScreen(),
                "/Report": (final context) => const ReportProblemsScreen(),
                "/Tutorials": (final context) => const TutorialsScreen(),
                "/FAQ": (final context) => const FAQScreen(),
              },
            ),
          ),
          PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
            icon: const ImageIcon(
              AssetImage("assets/bottom_navbar/profile.png"),
            ),
            title: "Profile",
            activeColorPrimary: Color(0xff2CC826),
            inactiveColorPrimary: Color(0xffFFFFFF),
          ),
        ];



    return PersistentTabView(
      context,
      controller: _controller,
      screens: screens.map((screen) => screen()).toList(),
      items: _navBarsItems(),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      navBarHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 0 ? 0.0 : 61,
      bottomScreenMargin: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom > 0 ? 0.0 : 61,
      onWillPop: (final context) async {
        return false;
      },
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
      selectedTabScreenContext: (final context) {
        testContext = context!;
      },
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF565656),
      //hideNavigationBar: _hideNavBar,
      decoration: const NavBarDecoration(colorBehindNavBar:Colors.white),
      screenTransitionAnimation: const ScreenTransitionAnimation(
        animateTabTransition: true,
      ),
      navBarStyle:
          NavBarStyle.style6, 
    );

  }
```

What I want to achieve is, whenever I press on a bottom `nav bar Item`, regardless of whichever `sub screen` I'm currently on, I want to navigate back to the desired `Parent screen` according to the nav bar item clicked. (Like on Instagram).I Highly appreciate if you can provide me a solution to this.

Hope you understand my question.Thank You!.